# WCF DataContract validation

Tags: wcf

I'm wondering if there is any data annotation which can be added to a DataMember in a DataContract, in terms of validation.

Let's say we have a firstname(string) datamember which we do not want to be more than 50 characters in length. Is there any way to catch it or do we need to implement a custom faultexception to throw an excpetion if the length of firstname is more that 50.

We need this validation for WCF security. Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature of the DataContractSerializer which allows you to specify validation declaratively by annotating DataMembers.

If you define your DataMember as a Property (as opposed to a Field), then you can write code to validate the data during deserialization, in the property setter. The code can throw an exception on validation failure or change the data (e.g. to truncate it to 50 characters in your example of a first name member).

```
[DataMember]
public string FirstName
{
  get { return ...; }
  set { if (value.Length > 50) throw new MyValidationException(); }
}
```

Comment: There are plenty of validation framework out there that allows for attribute based contract validation, starting with `Enterprise Library Validation Application Block` (not using data annotation though, it's all framework's custom validation attributes). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650484.aspx

Comment: No doubt. That wasn't the OP's question.

Comment: You answered (accurately), "there is no feature [...]". I then proposed an alternative, because, let's face it, I find it kinda ugly to implement validation in property setters.

Comment: @Paciv: Why not propose that as an answer, then, rather than commenting on mine.

Comment: My comment in itself doesn't answer the OP's question, as you stated. It needs yours as an introduction to be a rightful answer, that's why I commented.

Comment: Thanks. I went for simpler solution as we have already implemented codes for datacontarcts and operation. So I just truncate the string if it is more than I want in the setter.

Comment: Be sure to document this properly, or wish good luck to your unaware service customers.